# Get extra parameter from JSON array from autocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have next function for autocomplete an input:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
        source:"/autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 5,
        _renderItem: function( ul, item) { 
            return $( "<li></li>" ) 
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item ) 
                .append( $( "<a></a>" ).text( item.label ) ) 
                .appendTo( ul ); 
            }   

});
```

The JSON array contains 3 parameters ( value , label , extra ). How could I grab the third parameter and append it to another input text right after an element from autocomplete list has been selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event.

The event handler gets passed two parameters:

- the event object
- a `ui` object which contains the data of the selected item in `ui.item`

Example:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
        source:"/autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 5,
        select: function(e, ui) {
            // "ui.item" is the data item
            alert(ui.item.extra);
        }    
});
```

---

BTW, the way you try to override the `_renderItem` method is not correct, it should be:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source:"/autocomplete.php",
    minLength: 5,
})
.data('autocomplete')
._renderItem = function( ul, item) { 
    return $( "<li></li>" ) 
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item ) 
        .append( $( "<a></a>" ).text( item.label ) ) 
        .appendTo( ul ); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select: function(e, ui) {
        $('input#anotherInputTextId').val(ui.item.extra) ;
    }
```

Comment: You should consider explaining how this helps. Answers with detail are more likely to get upvoted. It also helps others understand why your answer is correct, when there is an explanation to go with it. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Guess I should have..thanks..will add in details after clarification

Comment: This function will be triggered on select, using the val() , you can replace existing value by passing value to it.The e is used to captured the event to do business logic.

Comment: You sure it doesn't go like this:  `$('input@anotherInput'.val( ui.item.extra );`. You should test your solution in a debugger. I'm sure you'll get an "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error. Use the "edit" link under your answer to correct + add details. :)

Comment: Sorry, the `@` was a typo, I meant `$('input#anotherInput'.val( ui.item.extra );`  When I try using `.val() = ui.item.extra`  I see a `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` error message. I believe the correct syntax is for the assignment to be within the val parentheses like so: `.val( ui.item.extra )` and not `.val() = ui.item.extra`. See the [val() docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and how the setter is a method. You should also edit your answer with the clarification and not just put in as a comment. ;). Use the `edit` option under your answer.

Comment: Corrected it .. thanks!.. i think assigning a function inside is more convenient according to the doc.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the right side after the equals sign. Now this looks great. +1